# Inefficient php / javascript code?

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code as shown below.
The code is working but the bottom part seems highly inefficient to me so I was wondering if anyone has any ideas how I can rewrite the code so that its not required to create a

```
baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[0]; ?>',
```

for every row?

(the $urls contain only text like in this way: something-more  (so no http: etc))

```
<?php
    include("includes/connect.php");
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT url FROM urls ORDER BY listorder ASC");

    $urls = array();

    while ($rw = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $urls[] = $rw['url'];
    }
?>

<script>
var baseUrl = '/';

var mySwipe = $('#pageBody').responsiveSwipe({
    edition: [
        baseUrl,
        baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[0]; ?>',
        baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[1]; ?>',
        baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[2]; ?>',
        baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[3]; ?>',
        baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[4]; ?>',
        baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[5]; ?>',
        baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[6]; ?>',
        baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[7]; ?>',
        baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[8]; ?>',
        baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[9]; ?>',
        baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[10]; ?>'
    ],
    widthGuess: 0,
    emulator: window.location.hash.match(/emulator/)
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.next', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        mySwipe.gotoNext();
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.prev', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        mySwipe.gotoPrev();
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: There's a separate site for these types of questions, over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. This should probably be moved.

Comment: use PDO instead mysql_*

Comment: what's not efficient about it ? If your array should have baseurl then it should have it. do you want something like factorization ?

Comment: So, you want to rewrite it to a `for` loop?

Comment: @Sekai: What is inefficient about it is that this code is unsafe (PHP to JS values are best `json_encode`-ed. fetching an array, and passingit on to JS is easily done by writing `var someArr = <?= json_encode($urls); ?>` job done

Comment: thx for all the feedback and tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `json_encode` after generating the array (including baseUrl) server-side :

```
<?php
    ...

    $baseUrl = '/';

    $urls = array($baseUrl);

    while ($rw = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $urls[] = $baseUrl.$rw['url'];
    }
?>

<script>
var mySwipe = $('#pageBody').responsiveSwipe({
    edition: <?php echo json_encode($urls); ?>,
    widthGuess: 0,
    emulator: window.location.hash.match(/emulator/)
});

...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your php:

```
$java_urls = '';
foreach ($urls as $url)
{
$java_urls .= "'/".$url."',";
}
// remove last , from the string
if ($java_urls!='') { $java_urls = substr($java_urls, 0, -1); }
```

Now in your javascript:

```
var mySwipe = $('#pageBody').responsiveSwipe({
    edition: [
        baseUrl,
        <?php echo $java_urls;?>
    ],
    widthGuess: 0,
    emulator: window.location.hash.match(/emulator/)
});
```

Comment: You probably want to wrap `$url` in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
var mySwipe = $('#pageBody').responsiveSwipe({
    edition: [
        baseUrl,
        baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[0]; ?>',
        baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[1]; ?>',
        baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[2]; ?>',
        baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[3]; ?>',
        baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[4]; ?>',
        baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[5]; ?>',
        baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[6]; ?>',
        baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[7]; ?>',
        baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[8]; ?>',
        baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[9]; ?>',
        baseUrl + '<?php echo $urls[10]; ?>'
    ],
```

Could also be something like

```
var mySwipe = $('#pageBody').responsiveSwipe({
   edition: [
   <?php
   foreach($urls as $url) {
      echo '/'.$url.',';
   }
   ?>
   ]
})
```